# PostgreSQL: How to treat upper/lower case as duplicates, not change case and keep earlier entry?

Tags: postgresql, group-by, distinct

In the following, 'abc' and 'ABC' should be considered duplicates. But I want to keep original casing and I want to take the earlier dated entry. So that I end up with: `abc, 2021-06-01`

I thought this would work, but it doesn't:

```
select t.s, max(t.d) from 
(
   select 'abc' s, '2021-06-01'::date d union all
   select 'ABC' s, '2021-06-21'::date d 
) t
group by lower(t.s)
```

throws this error: `Invalid operation: column "t.s" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function;`

What am I  missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PostgreSQL-specific `DISTINCT ON` construct.

```
select distinct on (lower(t.s)) t.s, t.d from 
(
   select 'abc' s, '2021-06-01'::date d union all
   select 'ABC' s, '2021-06-21'::date d 
) t
order by lower(t.s), d asc;
```

If you want something more standard SQL, you could use a window function to add a row number, then filter on that row number:

```
select * from (
   select *, row_number() over (partition by lower(t.s) order by t.d) from  
   (
      select 'abc' s, '2021-06-01'::date d union all
      select 'ABC' s, '2021-06-21'::date d 
   ) t
) t2 where row_number =1;
```